# View With CiviCRM Line Items

Tags: contributions, drupal-views, civicrm-entity

I am trying to use Views to create a report to easily filter by an event and then see the specific line items for a registration. I cannot find a way to list the line items for a specific contribution.

I have tried Views as well as CiviCRM Entity but I have not been able to figure this out.

Any ideas on how to do this are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2):

The Extended Reports extension includes Priceset Reports. It works great for our org to see reports with LineItem info.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports

Answer (score 1):

There's also this extension that may suit your needs:
https://github.com/Skvare/com.skvare.lineitemreport

Answer (score 1):

The LineItem entity is now exposed by CiviCRM Entity as well.  This gives line items exposure to Views.

I think all you are missing is some relationships to connect the event participant contributions, to the line items. This really wouldn't take a huge amount of effort to develop the finishing touches.